# jmeter recording does not work after windows 11 upgrade

Tags: jmeter, recording

Jmeter recorder suddenly stopped working for me. I just upgraded to Windows 11. Could that be the reason? Here is the error message.
I am getting this error when I hit the record button -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter stores keystore password into [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry), it might be the case the value was removed or altered somehow during the OS upgrade and the password doesn't fit anymore.

I think you can just delete `proxyserver.jks` and `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` from "bin" folder of your JMeter installaion and next time you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder it will create a new keystore with the new password and the error will go away.

You will need to re-import the `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt into your browser or operating system. See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter User Manual entry for more details.

Also there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter Test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you don't need to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Thank you @Dimitri T,  for your quick response. However, I do not see the keystore.jks in my bin folder. However,  when I search for that in my bin folder, I see  create-rmi-keystore.sh. I tried removing it from my bin folder and recording but that did not help.

Comment: Blzemeter seems to be recording only the first step ie loading the URL. All the steps after that like login and other clicks are not recorded at all. Any idea?

Comment: It should be `proxyserver.jks`

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve it. I had to run the jmeter.bat as an administrator and that worked.